# PassportJs, local strategy cannot be found

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to javascript and node. I followed the guide from passportJS and I am getting the error "local strategy cannot be found". I do not know why. my code, basically taken from the website at this point.

```
var express = require('express')
, routes = require('./routes')
, user = require('./routes/user')
, http = require('http')
, path = require('path')
, mongoose = require('mongoose')
, passport = require('passport')
, LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

app.use(passport.initialize());


//to configure the passport
app.use(new LocalStrategy({
usernameField: 'username',
passwordField: 'password'
},
function(username, password, done){
    console.log(username);
    console.log(password);
    People.findOne({username:username},
    function(err, user){
        if(err){return done(err); }
        if(!user){
            return done(null, false, {message:
            'Incorrect username'});
        }
        if(!user.validPassword(password)){
            return done(null, false, {message:
            'Incorrect Password'});
        }
        return done(null, user);
    });
}
));


//route to authenticate the user
app.post('/login',
passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect:'/accessed',
                                failureRedirect: '/access'})
);
```

My error is that "local strategy not found", I looked inside the local-strategy module and found the function that defines it. So I assume the error lies somewhere in the way I am attempting to access that variable.

My server is set up like

```
var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

  app.configure('development', function(){
 app.use(express.errorHandler());
});
```

Comment: `app.use(new LocalStrategy(...))` should be `passport.use(new LocalStrategy(...))`.

Comment: I changed that because with passport.use the function was never getting called ( i threw in a console.log) to test this

Comment: Could you post your server setup? Passport requires a bunch of middleware to be loaded, and the order in which they are loaded matters.

Comment: below the app.configure i define my mongo database

Comment: Add passport-local in your package.json and npm install -d

Comment: no luck with that, I get the error "local is no a strategy" with app.use and I cannot get the function to run with passport.use. I believe thats where I am losing the import of my local variable, I am going to try to add serialization and see where that leads me but passportjs indicates that it should be optional

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a boilerplate for using passport-local. The order in which the middleware is configured matters. It also implements serializeUser/deserializeUser which seem to be missing from your code.

```
var express = require('express')
, http = require('http')
, path = require('path')
, passport = require('passport')
, LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var app = express();

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) { 
  // insert your MongoDB check here. For now, just a simple hardcoded check.
  if (username === 'foo' && password === 'bar')
  {
    done(null, { user: username });
  }
  else
  {
    done(null, false);
  }
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) { 
  // please read the Passport documentation on how to implement this. We're now
  // just serializing the entire 'user' object. It would be more sane to serialize
  // just the unique user-id, so you can retrieve the user object from the database
  // in .deserializeUser().
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) { 
  // Again, read the documentation.
  done(null, user);
});

app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'secret' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// route to authenticate the user
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { 
  successRedirect: '/accessed',
  failureRedirect: '/access'
}));

// app.listen(3012);
```

When you use `curl -v -d "username=foo&password=bar" http://127.0.0.1:3012/login` you see you'll get redirected to `/accessed`, meaning the authentication worked.

Comment: Even I am getting the same error. My order of middlewares is same as in above code. What could be the possible reason for error "Unknown authentication strategy "local" "?

Comment: @user2235057 I think it depends on how you call `new LocalStrategy()`.

Comment: This is how I have configured passport. 
`passport.use({usernameField: 'emailAddress'}, new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) { 
  //code here})
); `

Comment: I have posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21454254/error-with-passportjs-unknown-authentication-strategy-local. It would be great if you could have a look at it.