# PassportJS not completing request

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

After following the answer found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15362856 (I had to add the `const` to my file due to the express middleware revisions). I can't seem to get the request to process. I'm using postman to simulate the post call, when I send the POST, nothing shows up on the server log and the request just 'keeps spinning'. Once I cancel the request, the server log says, `POST /login?username=foo&password=bar - - ms - -`

Here is my `server.js` file:

```
var express = require('express')
, http = require('http')
, path = require('path')
, passport = require('passport')
, LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var app = express();

const flash = require('connect-flash');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cookieparser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) { 
  // insert your MongoDB check here. For now, just a simple hardcoded check.
  if (username === 'foo' && password === 'bar')
  {
    done(null, { user: username });
  }
  else
  {
    done(null, false);
  }
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) { 
  // please read the Passport documentation on how to implement this. We're now
  // just serializing the entire 'user' object. It would be more sane to serialize
  // just the unique user-id, so you can retrieve the user object from the database
  // in .deserializeUser().
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) { 
  // Again, read the documentation.
  done(null, user);
});

app.use(logger('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(cookieparser); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyparser); // get information from html forms
app.use(session({ secret: 'nextoner' } )); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session



// route to authenticate the user
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { 
  successRedirect: '/accessed',
  failureRedirect: '/access'
}));

app.listen(3012);
// app.listen(3012);
```

Clearly I'm missing something, but after two days of googling I can't seem to figure out what it is. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you're missing route handlers for `/accessed` and `/access`?

Comment: I don't have them added but when I did, still didn't make a difference anyways. It actually shouldn't make a difference because Angular will shoot me to the designated URL without a controller or a view if a route handler doesn't exist I thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not initializing `cookie-parser` and `body-parser` properly.

Try this:

```
app.use(cookieparser());
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded());
```